# Trigger that fires when a new cell selection is made

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Have successfully implemented `OnEdit`/`OnChange` triggers.  However, these require an actual change to a cell.

It does not look like there is an analogous `OnSelectionChanged` trigger that fires when a new cell selection is made.

Any thoughts on how one might implement?

Answer (score 3):

Good news. There is a new Simple Trigger, check this [release note](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#april_22_2020):

> A new simple trigger, [onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee), has been added for
>   Google Sheets. The onSelectionChange(e) trigger runs automatically
>   when a user changes the selection in a spreadsheet.

The following code illustrates how to use this trigger:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  if(range.getNumRows() === 1 && range.getNumColumns() === 1) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().clearFormats();
    range.setFontColor("red").setFontWeight("bold")
  }
}
```

If you add this function in your sheet bounded script the selected cell will always be highlighted as bold red. Please, note that this is just an example. The `clearFormats()` call will clear the format of all cells in the active sheet, so take care with it.